# How do I store an XML value in my .NET App.Config file

Tags: .net, xml, configuration, app-config

I am trying to store an xml value in my app.config file. 
The app.config does not like this and I cannot use the `<![CDATA[` construct to ignore the XML'ness of my value.

Is there a way to do it?

Value example:`<FieldRef Name='LinkfileName' Nullable='True'/><FieldRef Name='Web' Nullable='True'/>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can save an XML document as text in an attribute value if you escape the character entities:

```
&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;Linkfilename&quot; ...
```

You can then use XmlDocument.Load() to parse the text value.

Note that this won't work for your example because your value is an XML document fragment and not a well-formed XML document.  You either need to wrap it in an enclosing document element (whose markup will still be escaped) or use a properly-initialized XmlReader to process the value once you've retrieved it from the configuration.